# How to check cutoff time before or after the current time instance?

Tags: datetime, java-8, datetime-format

Currently i am working with shipping condition. in this i will get `cut off time` against the company like (05.00 PM) .
Now i want to compare above time with current time whether it is before `cut off time` or after `cut off time`?
I have gone through all the link i can see only example with `date`. i could not find anything with time.
Please let me know or give a some clue so that i will sorted out.

This is What i have tried so far

```
String todayDate=LocalDate.now().toString("dd.MM.yyyy");

String s=todayDate+cutOffTime;//cutOffTime will get from DB
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm a");
LocalDate despatchDate=LocalDate.now();
try {
    Date cutoffDate=simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
    if (cutoffDate.after(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())){
        despatchDate.plusDays(1);
    }

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Do not mix the new and old date-time classes. The new ones are in the java.time package, built into Java 8 and later. The old ones are outside the java.time package and should be avoided (java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.text.SimpleDateFormat). The old class gained some new methods to facilitate conversion between the old and new data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Java 8 date/time api**

```
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
String cutOff = "05:00 AM";
DateTimeFormatter timeParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
LocalTime cutOffTime = timeParser.parse(cutOff, LocalTime::from);
LocalDateTime cutOffDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(currentDate, cutOffTime);
//After
cutOffDateTime.isAfter(currentDateTime);
//Before
cutOffDateTime.isBefore(currentDateTime);
//Compare
cutOffDateTime.compareTo(currentDateTime);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .why i am getting error if a change `AM` to `PM`?

Comment: Change the time format to "hh:mm a" if you are using 12 hour format.

Answer (score 2):

## Time Zone

The [Answer by Shiv V](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523067/642706) is going in the right direction, but is not spot-on. The answer ignores the crucial issue of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). The `Local…` types intentionally lose and ignore time zone information, that is their purpose. But we rarely want to lose time zone info.

Determining the date and time-of-day depends on time zone. For any given moment, the date and time can vary around the globe. A few minutes after midnight in Paris is a new day while still “yesterday” in Montréal.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class defines a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

If the desired deadline is “5 PM tomorrow”, you must specify the time zone as the context. Apply a `ZoneId` to an `Instant` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
ZonedDateTime zdtTomorrow = zdt.plusDays( 1 );
```

Now adjust to 5 PM.

```
LocalTime timeOfDayWhenDue = LocalTime.of( 5 , 0 );
ZonedDateTime zdtDeadline = zdtTomorrow.with( timeOfDayWhenDue );
```

You can compare using the `isEqual`, `isBefore`, and [`isAfter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-) methods.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
boolean overdue = now.isAfter( zdtDeadline );
```

You could also convert the zoned date-times back to UTC. The `ZonedDateTime` objects and their respective `Instant` objects represent the same simultaneous moment on the timeline (same moment in history), but seen from the viewpoint of different time zones (`America/Montreal` versus `UTC`).

```
Instant instantDeadline = zdtDeadline.toInstant();
Instant instantNow = now.toInstant();
boolean overdue = instantNow.isAfter( instantDeadline );
```

If you want to communicate the deadline to a customer in India, adjust into another time zone. The date-time value will represent the same moment on the timeline but will display with a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) that has meaning for that customer.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Kolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime zdtDeadline_Kolkata = zdtDeadline.withZoneSameInstant( zoneId_Kolkata );
```

If you do not specify time zones, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly, silently. Not good. For one thing, implicit assumptions make your code easy-to-misunderstand and makes bugs more difficult to pinpoint. Worse, **the default can change at any time**, when you deploy to a different computer, or even during runtime at any moment of your app’s execution! Better to always specify the desired/expected time zone. By the way, same goes for [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.